# Enumerable.Range to pull months back dynamically

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'm working on an MVC framework report where we are trying to restrict the users to two years of data (from today's date).  Per their requirements, we have a month and year dropDownList and the users are only supposed to see two years of data.  So, at present, if they chose 2013, they would only see the months of November and December.

Got the year DDL populated, now I'm trying to get the month list populated based on what year was selected.

Here's what gets me all of the months:

```
var months = Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.Today.Month)
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString(), Value = x.ToString() });

return new SelectList(months.ToList(), "Value", "Text");
```

New to these queries but feel like there has to be a way to do this within the query itself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What if they choose 2015, What will you show in the Months dropdown ? M

Comment: You would need a comparison somewhere in here to look at the selected year and populate the months accordingly.

Comment: @Shyju, 2015 would show all months to the current month.  Jan - Nov.

Comment: 2015 - 12 months
2014 - 12 months
2013 - 2 months

Comment: How about keeping this simple and having 1 drop down. Each option would display the year and month. "Nov 2015", "Oct 2015"..etc. Less work for you and easier for the user with less confusion over month drop down getting reset if they already have Jan selected but then choose 2013 for example. Easy to implement too: for loop that subtracts i months (where i is 0 and finishes when i is greater than 23) from datetime Now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it just inside the query:

```
Console.Write("Enter a year: ");
int year = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int maxYearsBack = 2;

var months = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Where(m =>
    (DateTime.Today.Year == year && m <= DateTime.Today.Month) || // This year
    (DateTime.Today.Year != year && (DateTime.Today.Year - year < maxYearsBack || m - DateTime.Today.Month >= 0)) // Middle and max years back
).Select(x => x.ToString());

Console.WriteLine("Months for year {0}: {1}", year, String.Join(", ", months));
```

With output:

```
Enter a year: 2015
Months for year 2015: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
Enter a year: 2014
Months for year 2014: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
Enter a year: 2013
Months for year 2013: 11, 12
```

And if you want names as well just change the last `select` to:

```
...).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(x), Value = x.ToString() });
```

Comment: Wow man, this was exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Not a very compact code, but might help you

```
List<int> months = new List<int>();
int year = 2013; //selected year
var today = DateTime.Now;

if (year == today.Year)
    months = Enumerable.Range(1, today.Month).ToList();
else if (year == today.Year - 1)
    months = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).ToList();
else if (year == today.Year - 2)
    months = Enumerable.Range(today.Month, 12 - (today.Month - 1)).ToList();
```

**Edit**

If you need the list of month names

```
//using System.Globalization;
string[] monthNames = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames; //all month names
List<string> ddMonths = monthNames.Where((m, idx) => months.Contains(idx + 1)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq, you can concatenate three different lists of months in one line of code:

1 - The months remaining in this year

2 - The entire next year

3 - The months of the following year up to the starting month

Give this a shot:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list =
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames.Select(s => s + " " + DateTime.Today.Year)    // Get now through the end of the year
                    .Skip(DateTime.Today.Month - 1)
                    .Take(12 - (DateTime.Today.Month - 1))
                    .ToList()
                .Concat(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames.Select(s => s + " " + DateTime.Today.AddYears(1).Year).Take(12))  // Tack on next year
                .Concat(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames.Select(s => s + " " + DateTime.Today.AddYears(2).Year)    // Tack on the last months
                    .Take(DateTime.Today.Month - 1))
                    .ToList();

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Here is the console output:

November 2015

December 2015

January 2016

February 2016

March 2016

April 2016

May 2016

June 2016

July 2016

August 2016

September 2016

October 2016

November 2016

December 2016

January 2017

February 2017

March 2017

April 2017

May 2017

June 2017

July 2017

August 2017

September 2017

October 2017